# Pandas: Percentage change as a column from the first value if the date is different in datetime index

Tags: python, pandas

i have a pandas dateframe like this where datetime column is index :

```
                         volume 
2018-04-08 15:52:26.110     43   
2018-04-08 15:53:26.110     17  
2018-04-08 15:54:26.110     10  
2018-04-09 12:40:35.877     15  
2018-04-09 12:41:35.877     16
```

My requirement is to add another column VolumePercentage where it calculates the percentage-change from a specific value which is previous value of 1st value in a group.

**Desired Output:**

```
                         volume  PercentVolume
2018-04-08 15:52:26.110     43       NaN (No previous)
2018-04-08 15:53:26.110     17       NaN
2018-04-08 15:54:26.110     10       NaN
2018-04-09 12:40:35.877     15       50% (from 10)
2018-04-09 12:41:35.877     16       60% (from 10)
```

Comment: Do you mean "percentage-change from a specific value which is previous value of LAST value in a group"? Your example says "(from 10)" and 10 is the last volume entry for timestamp 2018-04-08 15:52:26.110.

Comment: yes @JakeMorris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can add new column with shift to have an easy access in apply method to compare with previous group. And use just only first value.

**Data:**

```
data = pd.DataFrame(columns=['date', 'volume'],
                    data = [['2018-04-08 15:52:26.110', 43],
                            ['2018-04-08 15:53:26.110', 17],
                            ['2018-04-08 15:54:26.110', 10],
                            ['2018-04-09 12:40:35.877', 15],
                            ['2018-04-09 12:41:35.877', 16]])
data.date = pd.to_datetime(data.date)
data.date = data.date.dt.day
```

**Code:**

```
data['PercentVolume'] = data.volume.shift(1)

def func(df):
    m = df.PercentVolume.values[0]
    df.PercentVolume = (df.volume - m) / m * 100
    return df

data = data.groupby('day').apply(func)
```

**Output:**

```
                     date  volume  day  PercentVolume
0 2018-04-08 15:52:26.110      43    8            NaN
1 2018-04-08 15:53:26.110      17    8            NaN
2 2018-04-08 15:54:26.110      10    8            NaN
3 2018-04-09 12:40:35.877      15    9           50.0
4 2018-04-09 12:41:35.877      16    9           60.0
```

Is it what you want? I hope it helps.

Comment: @stockade do you really want output in this format "60% (from 10)" or it's just an example?

Comment: hey it is an example and this is time series and i group the index as index.date and i want to calculate the percentage change for every group with just the previous element of 1st element of a group. The first group percentage will be NaN as they don't have previous element @Anna Iliukovich-Strakovskaia

Comment: @stockade So is my answer what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can achieve this as below which is similar as suggested by @Anna, code as shown below:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['2018-04-08 15:52:26.110', 43],
                   ['2018-04-08 15:53:26.110', 17],
                   ['2018-04-08 15:54:26.110', 10],
                   ['2018-04-09 12:40:35.877', 15],
                   ['2018-04-09 12:41:35.877', 16]], columns=['Date', 'Volume'])

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.date
df['Vol%'] = df['Volume'].shift(1)

def VolumePercent(dfg):
    dfg['Vol%'] = (dfg['Volume'] - dfg['Vol%'].iloc[0]) * 100.0 / dfg['Vol%'].iloc[0]
    return dfg

df = df.groupby(['Date'], as_index=False).apply(VolumePercent)
print(df)
```

and it gives the output as below:

```
         Date  Volume  Vol%
0  2018-04-08      43   NaN
1  2018-04-08      17   NaN
2  2018-04-08      10   NaN
3  2018-04-09      15  50.0
4  2018-04-09      16  60.0
```